# Multiple vies on one screen controlled by separate classes in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, view

Good morning,
I am trying to achieve the effect of displaying several views on one screen. As a result, 2 views will be common for each activity, while one - the main one - will change.
I have activity_main.xml, activity_bottom.xml which has 3 buttons and activity_console.xml which has TextView, EditText, and Button.

I join these views to activity_main.xml with `<include>` - so far no problem. Each view displays correctly.
The activity_console.xml view, I want to control a separate Console.java class that extends AppCompatActivity.

Console.java:

```
public class Console extends AppCompatActivity{
private boolean isVisible;

private Button sendButton;
private TextView consoleText;
private EditText commandText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_console);
}

public Console (){
    isVisible = true;
    sendButton = findViewById(R.id.console_send_button);
    consoleText = findViewById(R.id.console_log_text);
    commandText = findViewById(R.id.console_command_text);
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return isVisible;
}


public void showConsole(){
    isVisible = true;
    sendButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    consoleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    commandText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

public void hideConsole(){
    isVisible = false;
    sendButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    consoleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    commandText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

`

In MainActivity.java, I define `Console console;`
in the `onCreate()` method I create the object `console = new Console ();`

then on one of the `onClick()` buttons I want to call a method on that object

`public void triggerConsole (View view) {console.hideConsole ();}`

Unfortunately, the problem is at the stage of creating the object
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {x.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo ()' on a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2325)`

Views are added to AndroidManifest.xml

What should the Console.java class look like to be able to control the objects in activity_console.xml from other classes?

Comment: Please read about `Activity` first before jumping into app development it will help you . You never create an Activity's instance in android the OS does that for you . For method calling i am sure there are other ways to do it .

Comment: I think fragments are more suitable for such.